# showing ListView error

Tags: c#-4.0

Am not able to do INSERT UPDATE DELETE AND CLEAR operatopns on my ListView in WinForms

Here's my Code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowData();
    }
    private void ShowData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("User id=sa;password=sql@123;database=arvind;server=ASHOK-PC");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Login_1",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        listView1.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

I got error in DataContext as

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListView does not contain a definition for datacontext and no extension method accepting a first argument of type System.Windows.Forms.Listview could be found.
```

Comment: oh i'm so sorryy for it.. but i was trying the code and got some how irritated.. so..hope not t to mind plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to follow a code example made for WPF when you're using Windows Forms.  The WinForms ListView indeed does not have such a property and in fact doesn;t support data-binding.

Do yourself a favour and use a DataGridView.  Just assign the DataTable itself to the DataSource property.  Binding the DefaultView is pointless.

Comment: please help me for retrieving my data from a table and show it in grid view with edit and delete button and operation , in a windows form....i will highly be obligated to you please.. help me..!

Comment: You already know how to retrieve the data and I've already told you how to bind it to the grid.  You can edit the data in-place in the grid and you can delete with the delete key.  If you want to delete with a Button then bind the Datatable to a BindingSource and bind that to the grid, then call RemoveCurrent on the BindingSource to delete the current row.